# How to add all Jar files exist in .m2 folder to maven libraries at once?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar, dependencies

I have jar files in .m2 folder, but they are not added as maven libraries when I open my project in intellij. I know how to add them one by one from (File > Project Structure > Plus sign > search locally for the jar file > choose it), But I need to add all of them at once since there are many of them (65 Jar file) and it's hard to add them individually.

Comment: The correct way would be to import the project from Maven per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start. All the dependencies must be defined in `pom.xml` file. IDE will configure them automatically.

Comment: what is in your pom.xml? have you defined any dependencies